# Why "exclamation mark" but not "exclamation sign"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

I wonder, why **`!`** symbol is called *exclamation mark*, but **`=`** symbol is called *equal sign*? Is it only tradition or there is something behind?

Comment: In grammar we learned it as *exclamation point*! So there's another data point for you.

Comment: Here's another data point (mark well :-) - an exclamation point is one of a number of punctuation marks.

Comment: In compsci we call it a ["bang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose it's in the origins.

**?** and **!** are from the family of language **punctuation marks**

**=** is from the family of **mathematical symbols** or **signs**.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis. Maybe some reference to back it would be welcome.

Comment: @Benoit I wish I had one, but it's just my supposition.

Comment: I think your hypothesis is good. Actually, `=` is no punctuation mark at all.

Comment: So, all signs used for punctuation are marks?

Comment: @Pmod: There are "quotation marks" too :)

Answer (score 3):

I think they're called *marks* because they actually mark something. That a sentence is a question, an exclamation, or a quote.

But `=` is just a sign, it doesn't mark anything.

Again, this is just another guess.

Answer (score 3):

Another difference I see is that the exclamation mark has no meaning on its own.  It is merely punctuation whereas the equals sign actually adds meaning to the sentence: life "equals" goodness.

Comment: +1 because it is interesting, though it doesn't really answer the question IMHO

Comment: +1 because it makes a pertinent point. "=" *means* "equals", and as such is called an equals sign.  Similarly "plus sign", "minus sign" etc.. The exclamation mark indicates that a sentence (or word or phrase) is an exclamation, but doesn't *mean* "exclamation", so there is no reason why the same noun should be used, and it turned out that we called it "exclamation mark". Similarly for "question mark" and "quotation marks".

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet, as my karma will not allow it. 
The exclamation mark was referred to as
 “sign of admiration or exclamation” in the 15th century
according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark

I think it is just convention.

If you think about the = sign, you can argue it "marks" equality. 
On the other hand, if you use "exclamation sign", in my mind, the street sign pops up.